# Como puedo guardar una propiedad li como cheakbox

Tags: php, sql, html5, sql-server, li

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Necesito poder guardar una `cheaklist` de manera que el usuario va a seleccionar más de un valor (hasta tres), pero mi `post` no agarra la propiedad de `html` puesto que estoy usando una etiqueta `<li>` y necesito guardarlo en la columna de proceso de `sql server`.

Comparto una parte del código:

```
<form action="conexion.php" metod="post">
   <ul id="myUL"method="post" action="datos.php"  name="picsform">
      <input type="radio" class="nobdrRtMid" id="proceso1" name="proceso">banamex</input>
      <li class="nobdrRtMid"  id="proceso2" name="proceso">vw</li>
      <li class="nobdrRtMid"  id="proceso3" name="proceso">banco azteca</li>
      <li class="nobdrRtMid"  id="proceso4" name="proceso">scotiabank</li>
   </ul>
```

EN PHP Le agregué una variable llamada `$proceso` la cual tiene un `insert into asg123()` ya validé y un `input` si guarda

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ni por qué declaras el  `ul` con method y action como si fuese un formulario ¿?

Comment: Me parece que el input="radio" te crea radio buttons y no permite selección múltiple, tendrías que usar algo como input="checkbox"

Comment: si como un formulario y pues use la propiedad li y ul para crear el diseñocomo el siguiente ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

Comment: Yo me refiero a esto: `<ul id="myUL"method="post" action="datos.php"  name="picsform">`, ahí tratas el `ul` como si fuese un elemento `form`. ¿Por qué? Si lo que quieres es elementos que sólo puedan seleccionarse una vez, como ya dijo @AntonioVenerosoContreras en su comentario, puedes usar elementos `checkbox`. Si les das el mismo `name` a varios `checkbox` solamente te permitirá seleccionar uno.

Comment: Yo me refiero a esto: `<ul id="myUL"method="post" action="datos.php" name="picsform">`, ahí tratas el `ul` como si fuese un elemento `form`. ¿Por qué? Si lo que quieres es elementos que sólo puedan seleccionarse una vez,  puedes usar elementos radio. Si les das el mismo name a varios radio solamente te permitirá seleccionar uno.

Comment: El ul lo cambie y lo metí a un form

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que requieres es elementos de los que solamente se pueda seleccionar uno, para eso existen los [input radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

El criterio es simple, si declaras varios input de ese tipo con el mismo `name`, no podrá seleccionarse más de uno. Por ejemplo, aquí, todos los input se llaman `proceso` y no podrá seleccionarse más de uno entre ellos.

```html
<form action="conexion.php" metod="post">
  <label><input type="radio" class="nobdrRtMid" id="proceso1" name="proceso" value="banamex" />banamex</label><br />
  <label><input type="radio" class="nobdrRtMid" id="proceso2" name="proceso" value="vw" />vw</label><br />
  <label><input type="radio" class="nobdrRtMid" id="proceso3" name="proceso" value="banco azteca" />azteca</label><br />
  <label><input type="radio" class="nobdrRtMid" id="proceso4" name="proceso" value="scotiabank" />scotiabank</label><br />
</form>
```